# Can I restrict an argument type to only class (and its descendants) that ALSO implements a given interface?

Tags: c#

I have a method similar to the following:

```
public MyData GetTransformedInfo(MyAbstractClass obj) {
    // Calculate and return relevant stuff
}
```

It's unlikely but `MyAbstractClass`'s children can have descendant classes.

I also have an interface, `IMyInterface`, that'd make sense to be implemented by a lot of different classes, including, but not limited to, *some* of `MyAbstractClass`'s children and their descendants.

The problem is, I need the above function to only accept `MyAbstractClass`'s descendants that ALSO implements `IMyInterface`.

I wished a simple `GetTransformedInfo(MyAbstractClass:IMyInterface obj)` would work but of course it won't.

I thought about using reflection, bailing out when not matching. But that's bad for several reasons. To name a few: it's not enforced at compile time, slow, allocates memory just for such a simple compatibility check.

Is my only option writing

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClassWithIMyInterface : MyClass, IMyInterface {}

public MyData GetTransformedInfo(MyAbstractClassWithIMyInterface obj) {
    // Calculate and return relevant stuff
}
```

and making those specific classes inherit from it? Is there any other alternative?

I believe it'd be the same problem if I had two interfaces and would want the method to only accept objects that implements both at the same time. So I guess this is the best I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generic function with constraints

```cs
public MyData GetTransformedInfo<T>(T obj)
    where T : MyAbstractClass, IMyInterface
{
    // Calculate and return relevant stuff
}
```

Comment: I may still be thinking in C++ templates. Would I need to specify the Generics argument everytime I call that function? Or the compiler will infer?

Comment: The compiler should be able to infer it in most cases. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'll try as soon as I get back from lunch. If I accept the answer, know that it worked. Otherwise, I'll come back here. Thank you!